# Create pop-up thank you message on form submit

Tags: javascript, html

I just added an e-mail sign-up form to a landing page and it works fine (using firebase as back-end btw). However, I'd like to either redirect to a **"thankyou.html**" page or have a **pop-up thank you message** appear upon submit.

How can I make it work? I know this is probably pretty easy, but I'm a novice.

Here's the code I'm using. Included this script in html:

```
`<script>
var signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
var signupSuccess = document.getElementById('signup-success');
var signupError = document.getElementById('signup-error');
var signupBtn = document.getElementById('signup-button');
var onSignupComplete = function(error) {
  signupBtn.disabled = false;
  if (error) {
    signupError.innerHTML = 'Sorry. Could not signup.';
  } else {
    signupSuccess.innerHTML = 'Thanks for signing up!';
    // hide the form
    signupForm.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
function signup(formObj) {
    // Store emails to firebase
    var myFirebaseRef = new      Firebase("https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/signups");
    myFirebaseRef.push({
      email: formObj.email.value,
    }, onSignupComplete);
    signupBtn.disabled = true;
    return false;
}
```

`

---

Also in Html:

```
<div class="signup">
<p id="signup-success" class="text-success" role="alert"></p>
<p id="signup-error" class="text-danger"></p>
<form class="signup-form form-inline" id="signup-form" role="form" onsubmit="return signup(this)">
    <input class="form-control" style="width:250px" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email goes here!" required>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="signup-button" type="submit" >Request Early Access</button>
</form>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You could use library like pnotify (http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) to display you popup.

Comment: Just call `alert` if you want a simple popup.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil that looks cool but above my ability I think.

Comment: @sebnukem That was what I tried originally but it didn't work... I tried to do something like this, but wouldn't gel...
                      <div id="signup-success" style="display:none" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        <strong>Thanks for signing up!</strong>

Comment: @sebnukem can you tell me how to use it?

Comment: You just call it? I don't understand where you are confused `alert("Thanks for signing up!);`

Comment: Sorry..I'm pretty much learning this as I go. Can you show me where to place that? I tried to include in the piece of the function below but its still not working. I've been reading about alerts but not sure where to place

Answer (score 0):

you could redirect your user with

```
window.location.replace("thankyou.html");
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
function signup(formObj) {
  // Store emails to firebase
  var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/signups");
    myFirebaseRef.push({
    email: formObj.email.value,
  }, onSignupComplete);
  signupBtn.disabled = true;
  // Redirect user to thank you page
  window.location.replace("thankyou.html");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work! I created the thankyou.html but still no redirect :(

Comment: did you put the window.location.replace("thankyou.html"); before the return false?

Comment: yea, I placed it right where you have it. I'm getting the e-mails but it still won't redirect..thanks for help btw

Comment: Got it working! I learned more and ended up using window.location.href="thankyou.html";  with return false below

Comment: window.location.href will make it impossible for the user to click back though :/